# Some server generated events do not get delivered to the client in production over websockets

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-websocket, maven-tomcat-plugin

**Bottom line:**

Some server generated events do not get delivered to the client in production over websockets.  However, the websocket connections get established just fine.

**Case study:**

I open Google Chrome and connect to our server. Open the devtools. Under WS tab, I see that connection got established fine, but I receive no frames when, let’s say, server needs to update something on the page. I wait for a while and sometimes (only sometimes) I get some events with a huge amount of delay. This works as expected locally however.

**Question:**

Has anyone seen similar websocket behavior and has any suggestions on how to eliminate variables for this investigation.

**Infrastructure:**

Server: Linux Tomcat

Two servers that handle:
1. Traffic from Devices (Communicating over TCP/IP with the Server)
2. Traffic from Users

Users and Devices are many to many relationship. If a user gets connected to a server that doesn’t have a device connected. This server looks on the other server and handles the info exchange.

There is a firewall in front of the servers.

Code:

https://github.com/kino6052/websockets-issue

**WebSocketServerEndpoint.java**

```
    @ServerEndpoint("/actions")
    public class WebSocketServerEndpoint {
        static private final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketServerEndpoint.class);


        @OnOpen
        public void open(Session session) {
            WebSocketSessionHandler.addSession(session);
        }

        @OnClose
        public void close(Session session) {
            WebSocketSessionHandler.removeSession(session);
        }

        @OnError
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            //Logger.getLogger(WebSocketServerEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, error);
        }

        @OnMessage
        public void handleMessage(String message, Session session) {
            try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(message))) {
                JsonObject jsonMessage = reader.readObject();
                Long userId = null;
                Long tenantId = null;
                switch (WebSocketActions.valueOf(jsonMessage.getString("action"))){
                    case SaveUserId:
                        userId = getUserId(jsonMessage);
                        tenantId = getTenantId(jsonMessage);
                        Long userIdKey = WebSocketSessionHandler.saveUserId(userId, session);
                        Long tenantUserKey = WebSocketSessionHandler.saveTenantUser(tenantId, userId);
                        WebSocketSessionHandler.updateUserSessionKeys(session, tenantUserKey, userIdKey); // Needed for Making Weak Maps Keep Their Keys if Session is Currently Active
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
            }
        }

        private Long getUserId(JsonObject jsonMessage) {
            Long userId = null;
            try {
                userId = Long.parseLong(((Integer) jsonMessage.getInt("userId")).toString());
                return userId;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return userId;
            }
        }

        private Long getTenantId(JsonObject jsonMessage) {
            Long tenantId = null;
            try {
                tenantId = Long.parseLong(((Integer) jsonMessage.getInt("tenantId")).toString());
                return tenantId;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return tenantId;
            }
        }
    }
```

**WebSocketService.java**

```
    @Singleton
    public class WebSocketService {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketService.class);

        public enum WebSocketEvents{
            OnConnection,
            OnActivity,
            OnAccesspointStatus,
            OnClosedStatus,
            OnConnectedStatus,
            OnAlert,
            OnSessionExpired
        }

        public enum WebSocketActions{
            SaveUserId
        }

        @WebPost("/lookupWebSocketSessions")
        public WebResponse lookupWebSocketSessions(@JsonArrayParam("userIds") List<Integer> userIds, @WebParam("message") String message){
            try {
                for (Integer userIdInt : userIds) {
                    Long userId = Long.parseLong(userIdInt.toString());
                    if (WebSocketSessionHandler.sendToUser(userId, message) == 0) {
                    } else {
                        //logger.debug("Couldn't Send to User");
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                //logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return webResponseBuilder.fail(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return webResponseBuilder.fail(e);
            }

            return webResponseBuilder.success(message);
        }

        @WebPost("/lookupWebSocketHistorySessions")
        public WebResponse lookupWebSocketHistorySessions(@JsonArrayParam("userIds") List<Integer> userIds, @WebParam("message") String message){
            try {
                for (Integer userIdInt : userIds) {
                    Long userId = Long.parseLong(userIdInt.toString());
                    if (WebSocketHistorySessionHandler.sendToUser(userId, message) == 0) {
                    } else {
                        //logger.debug("Couldn't Send to User");
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                //logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return webResponseBuilder.fail(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logger.error(e.getMessage());
                return webResponseBuilder.fail(e);
            }

            return webResponseBuilder.success(message);
        }

        // Kick Out a User if Their Session is no Longer Valid
        public void sendLogout(User user) {
            try {
                Long userId = user.getId();
                List<Long> userIds = new ArrayList<>();
                userIds.add(userId);
                JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
                result.put("userId", userId);
                JSON message = WebSocketSessionHandler.createMessage(WebSocketEvents.OnSessionExpired, result);
                lookOnOtherServers(userIds, message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Couldn't Logout User");
            }
        }

        // Send History after Processing Data
        // Returns "0" if success, "-1" otherwise
        public int sendHistory(Activity activity) {
            try {
                TimezoneService.TimeZoneConfig timeZoneConfig = timezoneService.getTimezoneConfigsByAp(null, activity.getAccesspointId());
                JSONObject result = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(activity);
                String timezoneId = timezoneService.convertTimezoneConfigToTimezoneId(timeZoneConfig);
                result.put("timezoneString", timezoneId);
                result.put(
                        "profileId",
                        userDao.getUserProfileId(activity.getUserId())
                );
                JSON message = WebSocketHistorySessionHandler.createMessage(WebSocketEvents.OnActivity, result);
                List<Long> userIds = getUsersSubscribedToActivity(activity.getTenantId());
                lookOnOtherServersHistory(userIds, message);
                return 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logger.error("Couldn't Send History");
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // SendAlertUpdate after Processing Data
        public void sendAlertUpdate(Alert alert) {
            try {
                List<Long> userIds = getUsersUnderTenantByAccesspointId(alert.getAccesspointId());
                JSONObject result = JSONObject.fromObject(alert);
                JSON message = WebSocketSessionHandler.createMessage(WebSocketEvents.OnAlert, result);
                lookOnOtherServers(userIds, message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logger.error("Couldn't Send Aleart");
            }
        }

        // Send Connected Status after Processing Data
        public void sendConnectedStatus(Long accesspointId, Boolean isConnected) {
            try {
                List<Long> userIds = getUsersUnderTenantByAccesspointId(accesspointId);
                JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
                result.put("accesspointId", accesspointId);
                result.put("isConnected", isConnected);
                JSON message = WebSocketSessionHandler.createMessage(WebSocketEvents.OnConnectedStatus, result);
                lookOnOtherServers(userIds, message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logger.error("Couldn't Send Connected Status");
            }
        }


        public int sendHistory(CredentialActivity activity) {
            try {
                TimezoneService.TimeZoneConfig timeZoneConfig = timezoneService.getTimezoneConfigsByAp(null, activity.getAccesspointId());
                JSONObject result = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(activity);
                String timezoneId = timezoneService.convertTimezoneConfigToTimezoneId(timeZoneConfig);
                result.put("timezoneString", timezoneId);
                result.put(
                        "profileId",
                        userDao.getUserProfileId(activity.getUserId())
                );
                JSON message = WebSocketHistorySessionHandler.createMessage(WebSocketEvents.OnActivity, result);
                List<Long> userIds = getUsersUnderTenantByAccesspointId(activity.getAccesspointId());
                lookOnOtherServersHistory(userIds, message);
                return 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public Boolean isUserSessionAvailable(Long id) {
            return WebSocketSessionHandler.isUserSessionAvailable(id);
        }

        public void lookOnOtherServers(List<Long> userId, JSON data){
            List<String> urls = awsService.getServerURLs();
            for (String url : urls) {
                postJSONDataToUrl(url, userId, data);
            }
        }

        public void lookOnOtherServersHistory(List<Long> userId, JSON data){
            List<String> urls = awsService.getServerURLsHistory();
            for (String url : urls) {
                postJSONDataToUrl(url, userId, data);
            }
        }

        public int sendClosedStatus(AccesspointStatus accesspointStatus){
            try {
                JSONObject accesspointStatusJSON = new JSONObject();
                accesspointStatusJSON.put("accesspointId", accesspointStatus.getAccesspointId());
                accesspointStatusJSON.put("openStatus", accesspointStatus.getOpenStatus());
                List<Long> userIds = getUsersUnderTenantByAccesspointId(accesspointStatus.getAccesspointId());
                lookOnOtherServers(userIds, accesspointStatusJSON);
                return 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public List<Long> getUsersSubscribedToActivity(Long tenantId) {
            List<Long> userList = WebSocketSessionHandler.getUsersForTenant(tenantId);
            return userList;
        }

        private List<Long> getUsersUnderTenantByAccesspointId(Long accesspointId) {
            List<Long> userList = new ArrayList<>();
            User user = userDao.getBackgroundUserByAccesspoint(accesspointId);
            List<Record> recordList = tenantDao.getTenantsByUser(user, user.getId());
            for (Record record : recordList) {
                Long tenantId = (Long) record.get("id");
                userList.addAll(getUsersSubscribedToActivity(tenantId));
            }
            return userList;
        }

        public void postJSONDataToUrl(String url, List<Long> userId, JSON data) throws AppException {
            List<NameValuePair> parameters;
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            HttpClientService.SimpleHttpClient simpleHttpClient = httpClientService.createHttpClient(url);
            try {
                parameters = httpClientService.convertJSONObjectToNameValuePair(userId, data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new AppException("Couldn't Convert Input Parameters");
            }
            try {
                httpResponse = simpleHttpClient.sendHTTPPost(parameters);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new AppException("Couldn't Get Data from the Server");
            }
            if (httpResponse == null) {
                throw new AppException("Couldn't Send to Another Server");
            } else {
                //logger.error(httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**WebSocketSessionHandler.java**

```
    public class WebSocketSessionHandler {

        // Apparently required to instantiate the dialogue,
        // ideally it would be better to just create session map where sessions are mapped to userId,
        // however, userId will be send only after the session is created.
        // TODO: Investigate Instantiation of WebSocket Session Further

        // WeakHashMap is Used for Automatic Memory Management (So That Removal of Keys That are no Longer Used Can be Automatically Performed)
        // NOTE: However, it Requires Certain Precautions to Make Sure Their Keys Don't Expire Unexpectedly, Look for the Commented Code Below
        private static final Map<Long, Set<Session>> sessionMap = new WeakHashMap<>();

        private static final Map<Long, Set<Long>> tenantUserMap = new WeakHashMap<>();

        public WebSocketSessionHandler() {}

        public static List<Long> getUsersForTenant(Long tenantId) {
            List<Long> userIds = new ArrayList<>();
            Set<Long> userIdsSet = tenantUserMap.get(tenantId);
            if (userIdsSet != null) {
                for (Long userId : userIdsSet){
                    userIds.add(userId);
                }
            }
            return userIds;
        }

        public static Boolean isUserSessionAvailable(Long id){
            Set<Session> userSessions =  sessionMap.get(id);
            if (userSessions == null || userSessions.size() == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // addSession() should add "session" to "sessions" set
        // returns: "0" if success and "-1" otherwise
        public static int addSession(Session session) {
            int output;
            try {
                final long ONE_DAY = 86400000;
                session.setMaxIdleTimeout(ONE_DAY);
                sessions.put(session, new ArrayList<>());
                return sendToSession(session, createMessage(WebSocketEvents.OnConnection, "Successfully Connected"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Couldn't Add Session");
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // removeSession() should remove "session" from "sessions" set
        // Scenarios:
        // sessions is null?
        // returns: "0" if success and "-1" otherwise
        public static int removeSession( Session session) {
            try {
                closeSessionProperly(session);
                if (sessions.remove(session) != null) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Couldn't Remove Session");
                return -1;
            }
        }

        private static void closeSessionProperly(Session session) {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
        }

        public static Long getKeyFromMap(Map map, Long key){ // Needed for Weak Maps
            Set<Long> keySet = map.keySet();
            for (Long keyReference : keySet) {
                if (keyReference == key) {
                    return keyReference;
                }
            }
            return key; // If Not Found Return the Value Passed in
        }

        // saveUserId() should create an { userId -> session } entry in sessionMap
        public static Long  saveUserId(Long userId,  Session session){
            // Test Scenarios:
            // Can userId be null or wrong?
            // Can session be null or wrong?
            try {
                userId = getKeyFromMap(sessionMap, userId); // Required for Weak Maps to Work Correctly
                Set<Session> sessionsForUser = sessionMap.get(userId);
                if (sessionsForUser == null) {
                    sessionsForUser = new HashSet<>();
                }
                sessionsForUser.add(session);
                sessionMap.put(userId, sessionsForUser);
                return userId;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Couldn't Save User Id");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // saveUserId() should create an { userId -> session } entry in sessionMap
        public static Long  saveTenantUser(Long tenantId,  Long userId){
            // Test Scenarios:
            // Can userId be null or wrong?
            // Can session be null or wrong?
            try {
                tenantId = getKeyFromMap(tenantUserMap, tenantId); // Required for Weak Maps to Work Correctly
                Set<Long> users = tenantUserMap.get(tenantId);
                if (users == null) {
                    users = new HashSet<>();
                }
                users.add(userId);
                tenantUserMap.put(tenantId, users);
                return tenantId;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Couldn't Save Tenant User");
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void updateUserSessionKeys(Session session, Long tenantId, Long userId) {
            try {
                List<Long> userSessionKeys = sessions.get(session);
                userSessionKeys.add(0, tenantId);
                userSessionKeys.add(1, userId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Couldn't Update User Session Keys");
            }
        }

        // removeUserId() should remove an { userId -> session } entry in sessionMap
        // returns: "0" if success and "-1" otherwise
        public static int removeUserId( Long userId) {
            try {
                sessionMap.remove(userId);
                return 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // sendAccesspointStatus() should compose JSON message and pass it to sendToUser()
        // returns: "0" if success and "-1" otherwise
        public static int sendClosedStatus(Long userId, JSONObject accesspointStatus) {
            try {
                JSONObject accesspointStatusEventMessage = (JSONObject) createMessage(WebSocketEvents.OnClosedStatus, accesspointStatus);
                sendToUser(userId, accesspointStatusEventMessage);
                return 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        // sendToUser() sends message to session that is mapped to userId
        // returns: "0" if success and "-1" otherwise
        public static int sendToUser( Long userId, JSON message) {

            if (sessionMap.containsKey(userId)) {
                Set<Session> sessionsForUser = sessionMap.get(userId);
                for (Session session : sessionsForUser) {
                    if (!session.isOpen()) {
                        sessions.remove(session);
                        continue;
                    }
                    sendToSession(session, message);
                }
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }


        // sendToSession() sends string message to session
        // returns: "0" if success and "-1" otherwise
        private static int sendToSession( Session session,  JSON message){
            try {
                try {
                    Long tenantId = sessions.get(session).get(0);
                    ((JSONObject) message).put("tenantId", tenantId);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("No tenantId Found");
                }
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message.toString());
                return 0;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    session.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                }

                closeSessionProperly(session);
                sessions.remove(session);

                return -1;
            }
        }

        // sendToSession() sends string message to session
        // returns: "0" if success and "-1" otherwise
        private static int sendToSession( Session session,  String message){
            try {
                JSONObject newMessage = JSONObject.fromObject(message);
                try {
                    Long tenantId = sessions.get(session).get(0);
                    newMessage.put("tenantId", tenantId);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("No tenantId Found");
                }
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(newMessage.toString());
                return 0;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                closeSessionProperly(session);
                sessions.remove(session);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably not the only bug, but your `WebSocketSessionHandler` class is not thread-safe. It uses `WeakHashMap` internally which is not synchronized. Concurrent access to these maps may result in unexpected behavior, which may or may not cause the effects you are seeing.

Comment: @defnull thanks a lot for your response! I will check if this fixes the issue and will give an update.

Comment: @defnull, you were correct pointing out the weakhashmap as a potential bug. Please post your answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

> Probably not the only bug, but your WebSocketSessionHandler class is not thread-safe. It uses WeakHashMap internally which is not synchronized. Concurrent access to these maps may result in unexpected behavior, which may or may not cause the effects you are seeing.

Turns out this was a correct assumption. A general rule of thumb: **Unexpected Behaviour ~ Race Condition**

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the only bug, but your `WebSocketSessionHandler` class is not thread-safe. It uses `WeakHashMap` internally which is not synchronized. Concurrent access to these maps may result in unexpected behavior, which may or may not cause the effects you are seeing.

(copied from my comment. Turns out this was the solution)